# JPA primary key auto generate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, oracle10g

my primary key entity look like below

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;
```

when i run, i get error

could not get or update next value;nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException:could not get or update next value

but when i just change to

```
@GeneratedValue 
private Long id;
```

no error throw . I want to generate unique primary key per table on **oracle** db .

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)` tells the JPA provider to use a table to get IDs from when inserting newly created entities into the database.

When using Hibernate as provider, this will result in a table `hibernate_sequences` which has two columns: the entity name, and the max identity already assigned to this entity. Here, it seems Hibernate doesn't succeed to get the next ID from it for your entity but it's hard to say exactly why because you didn't provide enough informations for that.

So, could you please provide the full stacktrace? Also, please turn logging with `hibernate.show_sql` property set to `true` and set the proper log level `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`. Join the log to your question if possible.

Maybe just check that you did configure the correct `hibernate.dialect` for Oracle. Actually, join your hibernate configuration too if possible.

PS: The "traditional" way to generate PK with Oracle is to use sequences (you could let Hibernate guess the best strategy for your database type using `GenerationType.AUTO` or force it using `SEQUENCE`) but I'll assume you want the resultant data structure be database agnostic. If not, I'd suggest to go for sequences instead.

EDIT: Answering a comment from the OP about `GenerationType.AUTO`. Indeed, the default is a single global sequence called `hibernate_sequence` and this might be a problem. But, with the setup shown below, you can use `GenerationType.AUTO` and still control the name of the sequence for the cases where the database uses sequences:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
private long id;
```

In other words, you can use use a different sequence name for each table without losing portability.

Comment: if i put GenerationType.Auto, it will use global incremental number, mean all my entities will increment the same number. The code run fine, but will it run out of incremental number?

Comment: @Pascal : If we are providing a SequenceGenerator does it help specifying the startegy as AUTO?

Comment: @Nrj Actually, if you use `AUTO` and if the database uses sequences, `@SequenceGenerator` will help to control the name of the sequence. But it will just be "ignored" if the database doesn't (e.g. with HSQLDB). So, unlike `SEQUENCE`, this remains portable.

Comment: thank you for the clarrify.  may i know what is the max number for sequence ? will it run out of sequence ?

Comment: By default the sequence's maximum number is 1E+27, or 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000. That should be enough :)

Answer (score 10):

There are 4 strategies for auto generation in JPA:

- Auto
- Identity
- Sequence
- Table

For Oracle auto generation primary key annotation, Sequence and Table are your choices. The basic logic is to define a generator first, use **@SequenceGenerator** or **@TableGenerator** respectively, then use the generator as attribute in **@GeneratedValue**.

This is a sample of how to use Sequence strategy:

```
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="SEQ_JUST_FOR_TEST", allocationSize=1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_GEN")
  private long id;
```

Here is an example of how to use table strategy:

```
  @Id
  @TableGenerator(name="TABLE_GEN",table="T_GENERATOR", pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", pkColumnValue = "MONITOR2012.T_JUST_FOR_TEST", valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1 )
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="TABLE_GEN")
  private long id;
```

If no generator specified in **@GeneratedValue** annotation, the choice will leave to the JPA implementation.

If you are working on database with existing tables, make sure you the sequence or the table defined in database before you run your application.  **The table generator will also need you to insert a line to the table before the @GeneratedValue annotation can work properly.**

Here is a tutorial about [how to configure primary key auto generation in JPA for Oracle database](http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-configure-primary-key-generator-in-jpa-for-oracle.html).

Answer (score 1):

IDENTITY:
Autoincrement on-demand, efficient due to database internal lightweight locking but does not work very well with hibernate due to “transactional write-behind” flushing strategy adopted by Hibernate.

SEQUENCE:
preallocate values to improve performance, supports well hibernates “transactional write-behind” flushing strategy.

TABLE (SEQUENCE):
One or multiple tables can be used to hold the identifier sequence counter. But it means trading write performance for database portability.

[short summary of Auto Generation](https://vvekpandey.medium.com/jpa-auto-generated-values-be5bd7f90200)