# JPA @MappedSuperclass different Id counters for subclasses

Tags: java, jpa, mappedsuperclass

I've got a @MappedSuperclass which is my base-class for all my entities (@Entity, direct or indirect through multiple sub-classing).

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@XmlAttribute(required = true)
private Long primaryKey;
```

The Id is generated like shown above.

My problem is that the @Id-counter is the same for each @Entity. In fact thats not a big problem because it would take a while to reach the Long.MAX_VALUE. But reaching that maximum value is a lot easier because there is only one counter for all entities. How can I use a different @Id-counter without having to add the above code to all @Entity-classes?

(If it matters for your answer: I'm using a H2-Database.)

Comment: I think you are worrying unecessarily. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807

Comment: Doesn't `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` has separate identity generator is managed per type hierarchy?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817625/jpa-primary-key-auto-generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database and tables support `AUTO_INCREMENT` change the annotation to this `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. Then the id will be generated during commit.

There is another way via TABLE or SEQUENCE strategy, but it needs to be explicitly defined per `Entity` which is problem for abstract `BaseEntity`. Just hava a look:

```
@Entity
@TableGenerator(name="tab", initialValue=0, allocationSize=50)
public class EntityWithTableId {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tab")
    @Id long id;
}
```

EDIT:
Well, so it is possible!
[MappedSuperclass - Change SequenceGenerator in Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589928/mappedsuperclass-change-sequencegenerator-in-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "SEQ_AAAAAAAAAAA")
@TableGenerator(
name = "SEQ_AAAAAAAAAAA", 
table = "SEQ_ENTITY" /*<<<==YOUR TABLE NAME FOR SAVE NEXT VALUES HERE*/, 
pkColumnName = "ENTITY", 
initialValue = 1, 
valueColumnName = "NEXT_ID", 
pkColumnValue = "packageee.PACK.PAK.YOURCLASSNAME",     
allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
```