# Element with that ID already exists in the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I am working on a practice Spring Boot project that lists/adds/updates/deletes math problems from a mysql database. I am using Spring Boot with JPA to do the database operations. In my case, the db already has the problems and the button 'listproblems' returns all the buttons to a table. I can edit/delete without a problem. But when it comes to adding a new problem, I don't know how to add the new entry to the database. At this point, I don't know what to share but here is the current **addProblem** method:

```
//This is in the ProblemController.java on the server side application

@PostMapping("/post")
    public void addProduct(@RequestParam("cont") String pcont) {

        // Get a valid pid first
        Iterable<Problem> problist = probRepository.findAll();
        int min = 100000;
        int max = 0;
        int gap = 0;

        for (Problem myprod : problist) {
            if (myprod.getPid() < min) {
                min = myprod.getPid();
            } 
            if (myprod.getPid() > max) {
                max = myprod.getPid();
            }
        }

        for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (!probRepository.existsById(i)) {
                gap = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (gap == 0) {
            gap = max + 1;
        }

        System.out.println("max: " + max);

        max = max + 1;

        Problem prob = new Problem();
        prob.setPid(max);
        prob.setContent(pcont);
        probRepository.save(prob);
    }
```

Problem.java Entity class

```
@Entity
public class Problem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer pid;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    public Integer getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(Integer pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

This function is basically iterating through the items to find the maximum index, then incrementing the index by 1 to get the next index. But It still doesn't work.

Please let me know if you want to see anything in particular to help me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're explicitly overriding the `id` here
`prob.setPid(max);`

which is meaning that spring is not auto-generating the next id. Resulting in primary/foreign key constraint violations.

Comment: Oh! It makes sense, Thank you!  I had a cloudy guess that might be the problem, but now I understand. Do you have any idea how can I fix it? I am looking to add new problems to the table. Kind of like appending the new problems to the existing table.

Comment: I would suggest just removing that line and trying it.  I am by no means an expert with spring or jpa. 


Here is a better topic on id generation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817625/jpa-primary-key-auto-generate

Comment: Amazing! This actually worked. Removing that @GeneratedValue annotation actually worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, that worked to add new rows. But when I delete an existing row, the newly added problem doesn't go into the deleted position. I mean, if I delete the problem with id as 3 out of 1,2,3,4,5,6, and when I add the new problem, it goes to 7 but not 3. That means the new ids are 1,2,4,5,6,7. I tried searching for solutions, but I don't find any proper resolution. Any idea?

Comment: That is the standard way that a sequencing of databases works. It will use the next integer in the sequence. e.g. last +1 . 

Also, I wasn't suggesting removing the  @GeneratedValue annotation but removing the prob.setPid(max);

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the `Problem` Entity it is a bit hard to understand the ID situation.

Just some advice. Take a look at: [objectdb](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id) and [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and check the part about @Id annotation and how to use it. Also, keep in mind that without looking at your DB, having the DB already filled with that primary keys is a possibility. I would suggest you add a method to clear the DB after each run or to use H2 in memory.

Comment: Hi @fjsventura, thanks for the reply. I just added the Problem Entity. And yes, I will take a look at those mentioned references. But please let me know if you have anything else after looking at the Entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Looking at the entity and your code, I would say that you are using the [The_Auto_Strategy](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated#The_Auto_Strategy) that will generate an ID automatically. You could just remove:

```
prob.setPid(max);
```

And your code should work.
If you want to set an ID you should use:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer pid;
```